# When starting Apollo, run start Error reporting during up

Tags: java

pid - 808 just quit unexpectedly, please check logs under /opt/logs/100003171 and /tmp for more information![enter image description here][1]

lsLinHaiZhao ~/Desktop/apollo/apollo-configservice/target/apollo-configservice-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-github/scripts (master)
$ sh startup.sh
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt’: Permission denied
Windows new JAVA_HOME is: /c/PROGRA~1/Java/JDK18~1.0_4
2022年02月22日 16:18:17 ==== Starting ====
LOG_FOLDER /opt/logs/100003171/ does not exist. Falling back to /tmp
Started [808]
Waiting for server startup.
pid - 808 just quit unexpectedly, please check logs under /opt/logs/100003171 and /tmp for more information!

lsLinHaiZhao ~/Desktop/apollo/apollo-configservice/target/apollo-configservice-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-github/scripts (master)
$

Answer (score 0):

1.Database password cannot be used: special characters can be used to modify the database password!

2.If the database is not started, the same error will be reported. Restart the database!

3.Not here Configure the contents of relevant databases in the properties file or YML file, and comment out the unnecessary or redundant configuration information, and restart it!

There are three possible mistakes, each of which can lead to the above mistakes. Carefully examine your own problems. Using these three solutions can solve your problems!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).